# Checking empty string in an arraylist

Tags: java, arraylist, is-empty

The arraylist that i am working on.

```
[Bibek Gurung, 9.808112115E9,  , tarkhya@gmail.com]
```

The code I've tried to check the empty index in an array:

```
if (!singleRecordExtract.get(2).toString().isEmpty()) {
 //but it passes through the validation
}
```

I've tried this but somehow, the validation is not working. And I wonder how?
Does anyone know the solution or a work around for this problem?

Comment: Why do you use ArrayList instead fields of class?

Comment: Because this array list is extracted from excel file and I want to set the values to the object of the Class that i want. In order to do so, I am checking for the empty fields.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The string in the list is probably " ". `isEmpty` returns false for strings with whitespace. You can fix this by using `trim()` which removes whitespace from the front and back of a string. This will make your string actually empty.

Comment: I did never think of that...It works perfectly fine now.